# MSSQL Cast as datetime

Tags: sql-server

```
    SELECT CAST('1753-05-08 00:00:00' AS  datetime)

SELECT CAST('1752-05-08 00:00:00' AS  datetime)
```

Уважаемые коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста этот парадокс конвертирования. В первом случае 1753 год все ок, во втором случае 1752 год ошибка летит

> The conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetimevresulted in
> out-of-range value

Comment: Нет никакого парадокса. Просто превышен интервал

Comment: если в байт вписать 257 то что должно случится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кусочек из [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> DATETIME DESCRIPTION
>
> Date range    January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999

Как видно в документации явно указан валидный интервал для типа `DATETIME` в пределах с 1 Янавря 1753 по декабрь 31 9999

Comment: Спасибо, ответ оказался очевидным, никакие настройки сервера здесь ни причём

Comment: @RomanIeromenko если ответ помог разобраться то галочка под стрелками

Comment: Есть, очень признателен